# Setting HTML height to 100% eliminates scrolling

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why this is not working.

I need to set the height of HTML and body to 100% for some setting the height of the three rows inside the page, but when I do this it eliminates scrolling, specifically on mobile devises but even on some browsers windows sizes when resizing.

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      display:block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      overflow:scroll;
    }
    .row1 {height:15%;} // header
    .row2 {height:70%;} // body
    .row3 {height:15%;} // footer
```

```html
  <html>
      <body>
        <div class="row1"> ...needs to be 15% height </div>
        <div class="row2"> ...needs to be 70% height </div>
        <div class="row3"> ...needs to be 15% height </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

If I remove the 100% on HTML then the page scrolls but the height, which needs to be percentage based, does not work. Any help on how to solve that would be greatly appreciated.

All the posts I found from googling and looking at code I have on other projects have not provided a solution for this issue.

Comment: If the div heights add up to 100%, there will be nothing to scroll. If there's more than 100%, [it can scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/o7cL95rp/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jjx9dypr/

Comment: By the way: You can not comment with // in css. Use the /*comments here*/ format

Comment: when you put the height of an element to be 100%, it is 100% of the parent element and in case of the `body` element, that would be the browser viewport which cannot be overflowed. I think you should change the `height` of the body to `min-height` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
html, body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      overflow:scroll;
    }
    .container{ 
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display:inline-block;
     }
    .row1 {height:15%;width: 100%;display:inline-block;} 
    .row2 {height:70%;width: 100%;display:inline-block;} 
    .row3 {height:15%;width: 100%;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
 <html>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row1"> ...needs to be 15% height </div>
        <div class="row2"> ...needs to be 70% height </div>
        <div class="row3"> ...needs to be 15% height </div>
        <div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Added style element and div container & take of the comment //

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this Code. Browser screen Sizes are different.So we wand to set height According to Browser Screen Size.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var height =$( window ).height();
alert(height);
var height1 =($( window ).height() *15)/100
var height2 =($( window ).height() *70)/100

$('.row1').css("height",height1);
$('.row2').css("height",height2);
$('.row3').css("height",height1);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

- As it is, it won't scroll since it should take up 100% viewport's
  height.
- Your css comments are wrongly formatted, use `/* comment */` instead.

Snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.row1 {height: 15%;} /* header */
.row2 {height: 70%;} /* body */
.row3 {height: 15%;} /* footer */
```

```html
<div class="row1"> ...needs to be 15% height </div>
<div class="row2"> ...needs to be 70% height </div>
<div class="row3"> ...needs to be 15% height </div>
```

Comment: You might want to explain what the wildcard css is doing (I'm personally familiar, but others might want to know what's going on with this and why it's included in your code).