# Detect scrollTop distance with body set to 100% height

Tags: jquery, css

I have a webpage that needs the height set because of scrolling elements on the page.  But I also need to detect `scrollTop()` distance to add some css to the nav bar.  It seems that setting the height of the body (which is the canvas in the css below because I am using slidebars.js) to 100% does not allow me to detect if the scrollTop has hit a threshold.

This is the js that I cannot get working.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > 175 ) {
    $('.navbar').css("box-shadow", '0 10px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175)');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').css("box-shadow", '');
  }
});
```

css

```
[canvas=container] {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc( 100% - 100px );
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white; /* Basic background color, overwrite this in your own css. */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Enables momentum scrolling on iOS devices, may be removed by setting to 'auto' in your own CSS. */
}
```

It simply does not fire if I have the height set on the body (canvas), but I need to set the height on the body so is there any workaround that allows me to set the body height but also allows me to detect the `scrollTop()` distance?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378248/setting-html-height-to-100-eliminates-scrolling) then you should be trying to detect the scrollTop of the element that is scrolling, not the window.  Otherwise  please include code (including the relevant CSS) that allows us to actually reproduce the problem you're having; as it is it isn't clear what's going on here.

Comment: unrelated to that question

Comment: I added the css,  with the height being set no scroll is detected, without it scroll is detected.

Comment: That's because the window isn't scrolling, the canvas is.  Check the canvas's scrollTop on the canvas's scroll event.

Comment: Darn, I was trying elements like `body` but you are exactly right, I needed to do `('[canvas]')` and that worked. If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrollTop` needs to be measured on the element that is actually scrolling, which in this case is not the window.

```
$("[canvas='container']").scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 175) {
    $('.navbar').css("box-shadow", '0 10px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175)');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').css("box-shadow", '');
  }
});
```

(I'm not entirely sure that selector makes sense, I don't know why an element would have a "canvas" attribute... I'm just going by what's in your CSS there. Use whatever selector returns the scrolling element.)